# Cannot create AVD because ARM EABI cannot find 'userdata.img' file

Tags: android-emulator

I installed Android 4.0.3, the jdk, and the ADT.  I try to make an AVD, and the error message says 'cannot find userdata.img file.'  I installed the ARM EABI v7a System Image in the SDK manager, and I still get the same error message.  I read a post that says "Even if you download the AVD Manager that is external to eclipse and says you have it installed, you have to go into eclipse with the AVD Plugin and re-install it as well. Have to do it twice."  I also did this twice, and I still cannot create an AVD.  I don't know what else to do.

I'm just a beginner, so please someone help me!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had already installed "ARM EABI v7a".  The following worked for me:

1. Install Android 4.0 (API 14) using Eclipse's "SDK Manager"
2. Create an Android 4.0 virtual device using Eclipse's "AVD Manager"
3. Now, try creating an Android 4.0.3 (API 15) virtual device.  This time, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to set the CPU/ABI field as "ARM (armeabi-v7a)" when creating the AVD.

[image]